# exec inside a function

Tags: python, exec

I am trying to run `exec` command from within a function. The `exec` code works fine when executed outside a function, but not when executed inside a function.

Please find the code below:

```
def func1(val1, val2):
    
    return val1*10, val2*10


def func2():
    
    val1 = 10
    val2 = 20
    
    exec('upval1, upval2 = func1(val1, val2)')
    print('Updated value of val1=', upval1)
    print('Updated value of val2=', upval2)
    
func2()
```

This code is throwing error as `NameError: name 'upval1' is not defined`

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Add locals (`exec("...", globals(), locals())`) or remove globals (`exec("...")`).

Comment: Why are you using `exec` in the first place? It's rarely needed.

Comment: @chepner, i am reading through a file that comes from upstream with some python codes in text format. That is why I am using exec.

Comment: @MechanicPig, but by adding locals() or removing globals(), the value of variables`val1` and `val2` is not updating.

Comment: Refer to the second note about [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec): *The default locals act as described for function locals() below: modifications to the default locals dictionary should not be attempted. Pass an explicit locals dictionary if you need to see effects of the code on locals after function exec() returns.*

Comment: @DumbCoder Why aren't you just *importing* the file?